# Как можно решить проблему с CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
const { data } = await axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', {
        action: 'query',
        list: 'search',
        origin: '*',
        format: 'json',
        srsearch: term,
      });
```

Comment: Проксируйте через свой бек сервер